Scipy Quad integration, The integral is probably divergent or slowly convergent
I am trying to use scipy's integrate.quad and it isn't working for my function.
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad

def cos_func (x):
    return np.cos(np.power(x, 3) + 1)

result_quad = quad(cos_func, 0, 10)[0]
print(result_quad)

I have tried with just x and x^2 in the cos function and both work fine, it's only with x^3, I have also tried using x**3 instead of np.power(x, 3) and that didn't change anything. Any help in fixing and explaining why it doesn't work would be appreciated.

Try flipping the 10 and 0:
The lower limit of integration is 0, the upper limit of integration is 10. The quad function takes in the cos_func, then the lower limit and then the upper limit.
result_quad = quad(cos_func, 0, 10)[0]

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html

Sorry I just copied it wrong, it's 0, 10 in my actual code

Are you getting this: IntegrationWarning: The integral is probably divergent, or slowly convergent. Doubt there's anything wrong with your code. Even here, https://www.integral-calculator.com/, there are some issues with finding the definite integral.

yeah that's exactly the error. I've used np.trapz, scipy.integrate.simps and wolfram alpha and they've all given the same value. I've just been assigned to use quad as well but don't know why it's not working

The x3 in cos(x3+1) will cause the cosine function to oscillate very fast near x=10. You would need a lot of nodes to capture all those oscillations. One way of circumventing that would be to split the integral range for x into [0,1] and [1,10] and make the substitution x=u1/3 to do the second one. (The substitution would be ill-behaved at x=0).
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad

def cos_func (x):
    return np.cos(np.power(x, 3) + 1)

def ucos_func (u):
    return np.cos(u + 1) / ( 3 * u ** ( 2.0 / 3.0 ) )

result_quad = quad(cos_func, 0, 1)[0] + quad( ucos_func, 1, 1000.0 )[0]
print(result_quad)

Output (I hope it's right!):
0.0451983043279886

Trying a home-grown version for the original integral (sorry, in c++!):
#include <iostream> 
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

double integrate( double a, double b, int n, double f( double ) );

int main()
{
   auto f = []( double x ){ return cos( x * x * x + 1 ); };
   double a = 0, b = 10;
   
   #define SP << setw( 15 ) <<
   cout SP "intervals" SP "estimate" << '\n';
   for ( int n = 10; n <= 1000000; n *= 10 )
   {
      double I = integrate( a, b, n, f );
      cout SP n SP I << '\n';
   }
}

double integrate( double a, double b, int n, double f( double ) )
{
   double dx = ( b - a ) / n;
   double sum = 0.5 * ( f( a ) + f( b ) );
   for ( int k = 1; k < n; k++ ) sum += f( a + k * dx );
   return sum * dx;
}

Output with number of intervals:
  intervals       estimate
         10       -3.00969
        100       0.559173
       1000      0.0424572
      10000      0.0451753
     100000      0.0451981
    1000000      0.0451983


https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+of+cos%28x%5E3+%2B+1%29+from+0+to+10 Looks like it should be around 0.0452.

Your mistake was you put the limits for the second integral as 1 to 10**1/3. The limits should be over u, and u = x^3, so they should be 1 to 10**3. Doing that gives the correct result, though you will get a warning about reaching the node limit. Change it to 1000 and it will be fine.

Ouch, my error! Thank-you @Jared. I'll sort out the node limit in a minute.

Because of the high-frequency nature of this function, you will need more points to get an accurate integral. The default is 50 subintervals for the adaptive method, but changing it to 1000 gives the correct result without any warning.
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad

def cos_func (x):
    return np.cos(np.power(x, 3) + 1)

result_quad = quad(cos_func, 0, 10, limit=1000)[0]
print(result_quad)  # 0.04519830321767172

